# Arrowheads cover the end of the ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks

When arrowheads are added to the axes, the ends of the ticks are covered by the arrowheads, e.g., ticks for $1$ disappear in the plot below,

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.03}]]
```

I would like to extend axis length a little bit to avoid the problem. How can that be achieved?

[image: arrowheads cover the ticks]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to extend axis length a little bit to avoid the problem

You can manually extend the plotted range using [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.03}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1}, {0, 1.1}}]
```

[image]